# Data import error with RODBC from Access

Tags: r, ms-access, rodbc

I am trying to import the results of a query performed on an access database into R. I can establish a connection using the RODBC package and I am able to retrieve records, so a connection with the database is not an issue. The problem is that two columns are inaccurate when I read them into R.

The query in access reads data from a table, and then produces two additonal columns based on calculations I perform. I import 18 columns, 16 of which are direcly from the table, with the other two being the calculated columns. When I perform this query in access, everything is fine. The results of the two calculated columns in access (the result of many IIF statements), which I will call V1 and V2, look like this in access after running the query:

```
V1        V2
A        -.1
A          0
A         .2
B         .2
A        -.3
C          0
A         .03
```

V1 takes three values (A, B, C), and V2 contains floating point numbers, ranging from about -.35 to 1.5.

These values are exactly what I want, so I know the query works when I run it in access.

I want to obtain these same values in R, so I run the same query that generated the above results in access like this:

```
query = "Select ..."
channel = odbcConnectAccess2007("DatabaseLocation.accdb")
df = sqlQuery(channel, query)
```

Again, a connection with the database is not an issue. After I attempt to run this query from R, the results of the two calculated columns (V1 and V2) do not match the results from when I run the query in access. The other columns, which are read straight from a table without any calculations, are as they should be. After running the query in R V1 and V2 look like this:

```
V1          V2
A           0
A           0
A          .2
A          .2
A           0
A           0
A          .03
```

For V1, every value is now the same (A). For V2, *some* of the values are read in correctly, but not all. Many values have been changed to 0, and now the lowest value in V2 is -.07, while when I run the same query in access the lowest value in V2 is -.35. The values that have not been changed to 0 are correct.

My next idea is to make a table out of the query in access, and then try and read in that entire new table. However, I would strongly prefer to do get the data the way I originally planned, and I would like to figure out this issue so I can avoid it in the future.

edit: I cannot show the actual query, because it's part of proprietary work, but here is a very similar query:

```
Select 
#First calculated column
(IIF(M.V3 = 1, 'C', IIF(M.V3 = 2, 'B', 'A'))) AS v1,
#Second calculated column, which is shortened from the real thing
(IIF(M.V4=0 AND M.V5 = 1, .0401, 0) +
  IIF(m.V4=0 AND m.V5 = 0, -.0441, 0)) AS V2,
#other values are directly read from the table
  M.V3, M.V4, M.V5, M.V6, M.V7, M.V8, M.V9, 
M.V10, M.V11, M.V12, M.V13, M.V14, M.V15,
B.VFIRST & B.VLAST AS M.V16
FROM MASTER_TABLE M
INNER JOIN B_TABLE B ON M.V10 = B.V10
```

Comment: It would be a big help to see the query and a sample of the original table.

Comment: It's part of proprietary work so unfortunately I don't think I can do that. What additional information about the query and table should I post?

Comment: Please see the edit above, I added a query which is similar to the actual one.

Comment: I still hope you find the answer to this question, but - just out of curiosity - why not calculate v1 and v2 once the table is in R?